# SQL Server - Select most recent records with condition

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by

I have a table like this.

Table :

```
ID  EnrollDate  ExitDate
1   4/1/16      8/30/16 
2   1/1/16      null
2   1/1/16      7/3/16
3   2/1/16      8/1/16
3   2/1/16      9/1/16
4   1/1/16      12/12/16
4   1/1/16      12/12/16
4   1/1/16      12/12/16
4   1/1/16      null
5   5/1/16      11/12/16
5   5/1/16      11/12/16
5   5/1/16      11/12/16
```

Need to select the most recent records with these conditions.

1. One and only one record has the most recent enroll date - select that
2. Two or more share same most recent enroll date and one and only one record has either a NULL Exit Date or the most recent Exit Date -  Select the record with null. If no null record pick the record with recent exit date
3. Two or more with same enroll and Exit Date - If this case exists, don't select those record

So the expected result for the above table should be :

```
ID  EnrollDate  ExitDate
1   4/1/16      8/30/16 
2   1/1/16      null
3   2/1/16      9/1/16
4   1/1/16      null
```

I wrote the query with group by. I am not sure how to select with the conditions 2 and 3.

```
select t1.*  from table t1
INNER JOIN(SELECT Id,MAX(EnrollDate) maxentrydate
FROM table
GROUP BY Id)t2 ON EnrollDate = t2.maxentrydate and t1.Id=t2.Id
```

Please let me know what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `rank()` window function, I think it's possible.

This is untested, but it should work:

```
select t.ID, t.EnrollDate, t.ExitDate
  from (select t.*,
               rank() over(
                 partition by ID 
                 order by EnrollDate desc,
                          case when ExitDate is null then 1 else 2 end,
                          ExitDate desc) as rnk
          from tbl t) t
 where t.rnk = 1
 group by t.ID, t.EnrollDate, t.ExitDate
having count(*) = 1
```

The basic idea is that the `rank()` window function will rank the most "recent" rows with a value of `1`, which we filter on in the outer query's `where` clause.

If more than one row have the same "most recent" data, they will all share the same rank of `1`, but will get filtered out by the `having count(*) = 1` clause.

Answer (score 4):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` coupled with `CASE` expression to achieve the desired result:

```
WITH Cte AS(
    SELECT t.*,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY t.ID
            ORDER BY
                t.EnrollDate DESC,
                CASE WHEN t.ExitDate IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,
                t.ExitDate DESC
        ) AS rn
    FROM Tbl t
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            ID, 
            COUNT(DISTINCT CHECKSUM(EnrollDate, ExitDate)) AS DistinctCnt, -- Count distinct combination of EnrollDate and ExitDate per ID
            COUNT(*) AS RowCnt -- Count number of rows per ID
        FROM Tbl
        GROUP BY ID
    ) a
        ON t.ID = a.ID
    WHERE 
        (a.DistinctCnt = 1 AND a.RowCnt = 1)
        OR a.DistinctCnt  > 1
)
SELECT 
    ID, EnrollDate, ExitDate
FROM Cte c 
WHERE Rn = 1
```

- The `ORDER BY` clause in the `ROW_NUMBER` takes care of conditions 2 and 3.
- The `INNER JOIN` and the `WHERE` clause take care of 1 and 4.

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/493817)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

```
with B as (
select id, enrolldate , 
  exitdate,
  row_number() over (partition by id order by enrolldate desc, case when exitdate is null then 0 else 1 end, exitdate desc) rn
 from ab )
 select b1.id, b1.enrolldate, b1.exitdate from b  b1
 left join b b2
 on b1.rn = b2.rn -1 and
    b1.id = b2.id and
    b1.exitdate = b2.exitdate and
    b1.enrolldate = b2.enrolldate
where b1.rn = 1 and 
     b2.id is nULL
```

The left join is used to fullfill the 3) requirement. When record is returned then we don't want it.